# Conversão de string modificada para a original

Tags: c

Eu me deparei com uma questão que pede para transformar um texto com caracteres "?" para a forma original, como por exemplo:

"C?m? mu?to b?m h?je" para "Comi muito bem hoje",

Eu escrevi um código para o programa principal que fosse capaz de ler as duas strings, original e modificada, passando pra uma função recebeString.

```
#define n 50
#include <stdio.h>

int recebeString(char original[n], char modificado[n])
{
    int i;
    int contador;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(modificado == "?")
        {
            i = n; 
            modificado[i] = original[n];
            contador++;
        }
    }
    printf("String corrigida: ", modificado);
    printf("\nNumero de caracteres corrigidos: %d", contador);
}

int main()
{
    char original[n];
    char modificado[n];

    fgets(original, n, stdin);
    fgets(modificado, n, stdin);

    recebeString(original, modificado);
}
```

A função não devolve a string corrigida e retorna um erro na quantidade de caracteres corrigidos. Alguém pode me dar uma luz no código?

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)` seu for manda executar enquanto _i_ for menor que _n_; quando acha um caracter "?", vc faz `i = n;`, então na próxima iteração, ele tenta usar um _i_ igual a _n_, dando esse teu erro

Comment: `modificado[i] = original[i];` bastaria você usar o mesmo `i` nos dois vetores

Comment: Muito obrigado! Eu dei uma corrigida e o único erro durante a compilação foi  `prog.c:10:23: error: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Werror=address]
         if(modificado == "?")`. Eu devia declarar uma variável do tipo char antes?

Comment: criei uma resposta pra pergunta não ficar sem :P acredito que resolva teu código assim!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Como falado no comentário, você pode usar o mesmo iterador para os dois vetores (*"modificado"* e *"original"*); quanto ao erro de comparação, `"?"` é um caracter, então você deve usar aspas simples:

```
...
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if(modificado[i] == '?')
    {
        modificado[i] = original[i];
        contador++;
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Eu só tive um problema adicional. Mas acredito que eu consiga resolver. `prog.c: In function ‘recebeString’:
prog.c:11:23: error: comparison between pointer and integer [-Werror]
         if(modificado == '?')`

Comment: ah, vou corrigir na resposta.. mas o erro diz que você tá comparando um ponteiro (no caso todo vetor `modificado`) com esse caracter; a comparação deve ser só do caracter específico (`modificado[i]`)

Answer (score -3):

Quando fizer um for tente usar o *strlen()* ao invés do tamanho do vetor. O tamanho do vetor só servirá se tua string tiver sempre o tamanho N, caso ao contrário irá ler 'lixo' da memória.

O *strlen()* de fato retorna o tamanho da tua string.

Segue o codigo, levando em consideração que ambas strings tem o mesmo tamanho:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define n 50
int recebeString(char original[n], char modificado[n])
{
    int i;
    int contador = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(modificado); i++)
    {
        if(modificado[i] == '?')
        {

            modificado[i] = original[i];
            contador++;
        }
    }
    printf("String corrigida: %s", modificado);
    printf("\nNumero de caracteres corrigidos: %d", contador);
}

int main()
{
    char original[n];
    char modificado[n];

    fgets(original, n, stdin);
    fgets(modificado, n, stdin);

    recebeString(original, modificado);
}
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).